# Jquery page layout change optimisation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and it works exactly as I want. The menu bar sits on top and recognizes the section it is on or in. You can click the links in the yellow menu to move between the sections.

Demos: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2atkZ/9/ and http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2atkZ/9/embedded/result/

```
$(function () {
    var $select = $('#select');
    var $window = $(window);
    var isFixed = false;
    var init = $select.length ? $select.offset().top : 0;

    $window.scroll(function () {
        var currentScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        if (currentScrollTop > init && isFixed === false) {
            isFixed = true;
            $select.css({
                top: 0,
                position: 'fixed'
            });
            $('body').css('padding-top', $select.height());
        } else if (currentScrollTop <= init) {
            isFixed = false;
            $select.css('position', 'relative');
            $('#select span').removeClass('active');
            $('body').css('padding-top', 0);
        } 


        //active state in menu
        $('.section').each(function(){
            var eleDistance = $(this).offset().top;
            if (currentScrollTop >= eleDistance-$select.outerHeight()) {
                var makeActive = $(this).attr('id');
                $('#select span').removeClass('active');
                $('#select span.' + makeActive).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });

    $(".nav").click(function (e) {
        var divId = $(this).data('sec');
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(divId).offset().top - $select.height()
        }, 500);
    });    
});
```

However, the code itself gets quite laggy as soon as you start putting any content in the boxes. According to help I've received, it's that I am repeatedly changing page layout properties via the animation and querying page layout properties in the scroll handler, thus triggering a large number of forced layouts.

[User Tibos said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23651747/1048572) that:

> You could get a big improvement by disabling the scroll handler during
>   the click animation and instead triggering the effects with no checks
>   made (set the active class on the clicked element).

Could anyone show me how I can achieve this optimization?

Comment: Do you have lots of images on the page? If you do, then I suggest making sure they are all as optimized (and small) as they can get, and also use sprites where appropriate. Image decoding tends to cause a lot of performance loss because browser pauses during page rendering while decoding them. If that doesn't help, you'll probably have to 'optimize' the animations using CSS3.

Comment: Also, make it a habit to use this tool: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline It's for Chrome, but it tells you a lot of things about how the page is rendered (and re-rendered during animation).

Comment: The suggestion you mentioned just requires turning "off" the scroll handler. I added it here http://jsfiddle.net/vDGeg/ , but it's highly possible you'll still see performance issues depending on how complicated your page is.

Comment: @bvukelic wow i think this one of those questions which should be protected .Today itself i have seen Many Similar questions with trying to accomplish different parts he have implemented here its really one stop solution for many

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Kyle. Could be many many many things, frustratingly many things. :)))

Comment: using things like `$('.section').each` inside the scroll event callback is insanely expensive and should be avoided. and for the rest of your "code", you are doing a lot of unnecessary computation here. a LOT.

Comment: @vsync Well that's exactly my point, I feel like I have the outcome I want at the moment but not the correct technique

Comment: @Jimmy: Selecting stuff with complex selectors (and generally selecting stuff), getting or setting CSS properties, those can be surprisingly expensive. When changing appearance of stuff, try to use classes as much as possible, and use cached selectors to improve performance. But again, it may be something else. :P

Comment: I'll post the perfect solution soon.

Comment: Add `if ($('body').is(':animated')) return;` at the top of your scroll handler to prevent any further execution when the body is being animated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/vsync/2atkZ/14/) and another concept demo: http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/Kgcoa

The KEY here is to position your `select` inside another element, so when it get's FIXED to the screen, it won't affect the other elements by the sudden lack of height it once physically occupied. I've added a little CSS also. It's important to use the jQuery version 1.11 or above, because they fixed a but that caused the same class to be added again and again, regardless if an element already has it. bad for performance. Also, I've used a `for` loop and not jquery `each` loop on the sections elements, because a for loop is much faster due to the lack of function callback an `each` function has. Also, a very important thing is to make sure that every element that can be cached is actually cached, so we don't look for it endlessly in the DOM...

For showing which section we're on, I'm looping on all the sections, starting for the last one, which is important to, and checking if each top has passed the window's top using `getBoundingClientRect` method for knowing such thing. This helps knowing where we are.

```
var pos,
    $el = $('#select'),
    navItems = $el.find('.nav'),
    menuHeight = $el[0].clientHeight,
    scrollY,
    sections = $('.section').toArray(),  // cache sections elements
    pointOfAttachment = $('.jumbo')[0].clientHeight - menuHeight;

// Bind events
$(window).on('scroll.nav', updateNav)
         .on('resize.nav', updateNav);


function updateNav(){
    scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    for( var i = sections.length; i--; ){
        if( sections[i].getBoundingClientRect().top < 0 ){
            navItems.filter('.' + sections[i].id).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            break;
        }
        navItems.removeClass('active');
    }

    if( scrollY > pointOfAttachment )
        $el.addClass('fixed');
    else
        $el.removeClass('fixed');
}
```

## Why is this optimal?

The key for good performance is to do as minimal as possible to achieve your goal, and minimal here means accessing the DOM as little as possible and changing it even less times than accessing it. This is HIGHLY optimal code which ONLY changes the DOM when a change is required and never in any other situation.

Comment: I will award the bounty as soon as it allows me. But really, this is a carefully considered, efficient and beautiful answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcomed. The how to make it optimal is as important as to understand why this is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do this on each `scroll` event. You could throttle the event and only run the callback something like every 20ms. The user shouldn't notice. You can do this with [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#throttle), or write your own solution.

Another thing that would ease the lagg is to move as much out of the scroll event callback as possible. You don't need to query `$('body')` all the time for example, save that to a variable.